# WorkFlow logic for parallel task processes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I'm attempting to create a WorkFlow that uses task processes in a parallel block in SPD 2013. The code I currently have is:

```
These actions will run in parallel:

Start task process with these users 
If variable equals yes
Start task process with these users
```

I have multiple blocks of code of this the code causes my workflow to take minutes to publish and is throwing errors of timeouts. Is there a better logic to do this? I feel like I'm overthinking this.

Comment: How many total task process actions does the workflow have?

Comment: 21 as of now, but the workflow will require much more than that when finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 21 and counting task actions, I'd redesign. Perhaps you could do all the conditional logic to determine who to assign the task to, and then have one task that uses all those predetermined variables to use for the assigned to, task message, etc? Or, perhaps you could break it into several different workflows?

Even if it worked with a few dozen tasks, testing/troubleshooting would be a major pain.